# TypeScript validation of an exported array

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, typescript-typings

I am trying to import a config.ts file which looks like this:

```
export default [
    {
        //Required
        sender: 'admin',
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',

        //Optional
        newEmailsOnly: true, // default: true
        renameCallback: (originalFilename: string) => 'test.pdf',
    },
    {
        ...
    }
];
```

I want to import it in my index.ts file, and i want it to warn me if the configuration file is not properly written, so I have this interface:

```
export interface Config {
    sender: string;
    mimeType: string;

    newEmailsOnly?: boolean;
    renameCallback?: (originalFilename: string) => string;
}
```

I know I am supposed to write a `declare module 'config'` but i'm kind of lost since I am exporting an array of objects...

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```ts
export const myConfig: Config[] = [
    {
        //Required
        sender: 'admin',
        mimeType: 'application/pdf',

        //Optional
        newEmailsOnly: true, // default: true
        renameCallback: (originalFilename: string) => 'test.pdf',
    }
];

export interface Config {
    sender: string;
    mimeType: string;

    newEmailsOnly?: boolean;
    renameCallback?: (originalFilename: string) => string;
}
```

In typescript you can denote an array of `x` by suffixing the type with `[]`:

`A[];`
`B[];`
`Config[]`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I thought this has to be done in a `d.ts`file.

Comment: `d.ts` is mainly used to accompany a `js` file which has no notion of types, whereas a `ts` file has all the type information baked in.

Comment: Ok. This is handy. So the keyword `declare` shouldn't be used when we're talking about js files, right ?

Comment: `declare` should not be used directly in a `js` file, no. Generally `declare` is only used for telling typescript about an external `js` library that has no types. Lets say a lib adds `SomeClass` to the window but it has no associated types - typescript might complain about `SomeClass` not existing, to remedy this I can `declare var SomeClass: any`. This tells typescript "`SomeClass` exists, but I don't know much about it, just let me use it." https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=declare%20var%20SomeClass%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0ASomeClass.something()

Comment: Ok, i wasn't sure. Thanks for the help mate

Comment: This is correct but i see no reason to change to a named export.